# How to configure CLion and clang-tidy for 'Signature is not normalized' warnings

Tags: c++, qt, clion

I am writing a c++ program in QT using CLion

I am using a lot of connections in my code. When the slot does not have parameters I have no problems, but when the slot have some parameter, like this:

```
SIGNAL(showCssResults(QStringList & ))
```

clang-tidy warns me with 'Signature is not normalized' like this:

```
SIGNAL(showCssResults(QStringList&))
```

I can configure the editor>code style to remove spaces after and before &, but this affects the function definition, but not the example above

My questions:

- Is there a way to autoformat in CLion to convert signatures (remove spaces) without changing the slot declaration (I want the space before the &)?
- Is there a way change this behavior in clang tidy?

Thanks to all